# AngularJS: ng-repeat not showing data (Mixing Django and Angular template expressions)

Tags: angularjs, django

index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html ng-app = "myModule">
    <head>
        <script src = '{% static "scripts/angular.js" %}'> </script>
        <script src = '{% static "scripts/application.js" %}'> </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller = "myController">
    Table: Message: {{ message }}
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "t in technologies track by $index">
            <td> {{ t.name }} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

application.js:

```
// Create a module
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);

// Create a controller. Attach model to the scope.
var myContoller = function ($scope, $http, $log) {
    var technologies = [{name: "C", likes: 0, dislikes: 0},
                        {name: "Perl", likes: 0, dislikes: 0},
                        {name: "Java", likes: 0, dislikes: 0},
                        {name: "Python", likes: 0, dislikes: 0}];

    $scope.technologies = technologies;
    $scope.message = 'AngularJS table';
}

// Register the controller with the module
myApp.controller("myController", myContoller);
```

When I opened index.html, No data from the model gets displayed. Am I missing something obvious?

I am only showing the html and controller files here. But the code is part of a Django project.

Comment: You are mixing up Django and angular. The `{{ t.name }}` is interpreted by Django, and since it can probably not find any `t`, it is blank. So angular never sees the `{{ t.name }}` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you *mix Django templates and angular templates*. This means that if you write:

```
{{ t.name }}
```

This is *first* interpreted by the Django template rendering. In case such `t` exists (with a `name` attribute or element), then it renders the content. If not it will replace it with an empty string (or another error string you have configured). Regardless by what it is replaced, the `{{ t.name }}` itself is gone.

So the "Angular template" (the endproduct of rendering the Django template) never sees this tag. There are however mechanisms to prevent Django from interpreting the `{{ }}` parts (and other template tags as well).

You can use the [**`verbatim`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) to diable the django template engine at some specific part. So by writing it like:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html ng-app = "myModule">
    <head>
        <script src = '{% static "scripts/angular.js" %}'> </script>
        <script src = '{% static "scripts/application.js" %}'> </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller = "myController">
    Table: Message: {% verbatim %}{{ message }}{% endverbatim %}
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "t in technologies track by $index">
            <td> {% verbatim %}{{ t.name }}{% endverbatim %} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

So now `{{ t.name }}` will *not* get evaluated by the Django template engine, and it simply renders `{{ t.name }}` as output. This can then be interpreted by the "Angular template engine" and substituted by the values in the list.

The [`django-angular` documentation](https://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#template-tags) has a section on this subject.